# What kind of performance can I expect from using a Raspberry Pi as a webserver?

Tags: performance, web-server, benchmarking

Has anyone done some [web server benchmarking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking) on their Raspi?  I don't have my Raspi yet but I'm planning on using it as a web server and I'm interested to see stats for:

- Number of requests per second
- Latency response time between requests
- Throughput (i.e. bytes per second)

If these are different for different web server software and OS combinations I'd also be interested to see a comparison.

Comment: Can the vote to close please explain why?  This is an objective question with an objective measurable answer.

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively, but I reckon the fastest web servers in general are going to be the fastest on the RPi. My preference, Nginx.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Thanks, useful to know, but I'd still be interested in seeing the kind of performance I can get from the device so I don't plan using it for a project beyond its capabilities...

Comment: See this page: https://cheapskatesguide.org/articles/raspberry-pi-webserver.html.
The first part of the article talks about performance with a Lighttpd webserver.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I expect that, as Alex says, the benchmarks will show that the fastest Linux webservers will still be the fastest, regardless of architecture.

If anyone wants to run benchmarks then the following tutorial has been useful to me:

[How to perform benchmarks on a web-server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html)

---

## Serving Static Pages

I have tested the RPi using Apache serving a simple static page:

```
<h1>It works!</h1>
```

---

As a control group I used my primary webserver which totes the following spec;

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X3323  @ 2.50GHz
384MB RAM
```

---

The results are as follows:

**Control**

```
ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://www.ivings.org.uk/~james/index.html

Server Software:        Apache/2.2.14
Server Hostname:        www.ivings.org.uk
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /~james/index.html
Document Length:        19 bytes

Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   17.767 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      294000 bytes
HTML transferred:       19000 bytes
Requests per second:    56.29 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       88.833 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       17.767 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          16.16 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       42   44   0.8     44      50
Processing:    44   45   0.9     45      59
Waiting:       44   45   0.9     45      59
Total:         86   89   1.3     88     108

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     88
  66%     89
  75%     89
  80%     89
  90%     90
  95%     91
  98%     91
  99%     94
 100%    108 (longest request)
```

**Raspberry Pi**

```
ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://86.137.189.68/index.html

Server Software:        Apache/2.2.22
Server Hostname:        86.137.189.68
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index.html
Document Length:        19 bytes

Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   23.186 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      304000 bytes
HTML transferred:       19000 bytes
Requests per second:    43.13 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       115.930 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       23.186 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          12.80 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       40   44   5.6     43     116
Processing:    49   71 156.1     57    2157
Waiting:       47   53   6.7     55     104
Total:         91  116 156.1     99    2198

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     99
  66%    100
  75%    100
  80%    100
  90%    102
  95%    126
  98%    150
  99%    667
 100%   2198 (longest request)
```

---

**Conclusion**

**Note:** This is best treated as an estimate.

The results show that the Raspberry Pi actually performed damn well considering. It was only slightly less responsive than my primary webserver.

It should be fine handling a reasonably large number of requests.

Comment: That may be so, but what kind of performance can the fastest produce?  I think you have both misunderstood what I'm trying to ask...

Comment: I will perform some benchmarks on apache and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks.  I apologise if my question wasn't clear.  Perhaps I muddied the water asking for comparison, when really stats for a standard LAMP stack was my main interest.

Comment: The "A" in LAMP stands for the Apache HTTP server...

Comment: @RogerDahl: Yes it does. Why did you say that?

Comment: @Jivings: It was a comment meant for the OP. In the initial comment to your post, he indicated that he's interested in finding the performance of the fastest http server and seemed unhappy with your Apache based benchmark. Then he went on to implicitly ask for an Apache benchmark (the "A" in LAMP).

Comment: interesting. a "pie farm" might be a very cost effective server solution.

Comment: @Jivings I see a public IP address on the Pi, but I doubt that your server and Pi have the same fast network connection. Are you able to conduct the experiment in a LAN? Can you test this with access logs disabled (or at least to tmpfs). Without access logs disabled, your results will be greatly influenced by the speed of your SD card.

Comment: @Lekensteyn These are good points. If I get a chance I will redo the experiment.

Answer (score 5):

Apache is not the best choice when serving static content, nginx is better suited for that. I did a benchmark using http://lekensteyn.nl/index.html as test document. It is a larger document than Jiving's example since 19 bytes is not realistic for an actual page. The results are quite amazing, the RPi even outperforms my work laptop (maybe because I have all kinds of kernel debugging switches enabled).

Here is nginx 1.4.1 running on Arch Linux (RPi, `access_log off`, wired ethernet):

```
$ ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://192.168.2.10/index.html

Server Software:        nginx/1.4.1
Server Hostname:        192.168.2.10
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index.html
Document Length:        2159 bytes

Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   2.341 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      2392000 bytes
HTML transferred:       2159000 bytes
Requests per second:    427.18 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       11.705 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.341 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          997.86 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   0.1      1       1
Processing:     4   11   1.0     11      20
Waiting:        3   11   1.0     10      19
Total:          4   12   1.0     12      21

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     12
  66%     12
  75%     12
  80%     12
  90%     12
  95%     12
  98%     17
  99%     18
 100%     21 (longest request)
```

This is my laptop (`access_log off`, wired ethernet):

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.4.1
Server Hostname:        192.168.2.12
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index.html
Document Length:        2159 bytes

Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   2.593 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      2392000 bytes
HTML transferred:       2159000 bytes
Requests per second:    385.62 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       12.966 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.593 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          900.79 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        2    6   3.4      5      82
Processing:     3    7   5.6      6      86
Waiting:        3    7   5.5      5      82
Total:          6   13   6.8     12      94

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     12
  66%     13
  75%     14
  80%     15
  90%     17
  95%     19
  98%     24
  99%     34
 100%     94 (longest request)
```

For completeness, my remote server. It is slower with the WAN connection being the likely bottleneck (`access_log` is not off either):

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.2.8
Server Hostname:        lekensteyn.nl
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index.html
Document Length:        2159 bytes

Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   11.074 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      2370000 bytes
HTML transferred:       2159000 bytes
Requests per second:    90.30 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       55.371 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       11.074 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          209.00 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       25   27   2.3     26      59
Processing:    28   29   2.3     28      59
Waiting:       26   27   2.4     27      59
Total:         53   55   3.8     55     102

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     55
  66%     55
  75%     55
  80%     55
  90%     56
  95%     57
  98%     59
  99%     86
 100%    102 (longest request)
```

With more concurrency and higher requests count, the numbers should be more reliable as more samples can be included (when I ran `ab` against my laptop in wires/wireless mode, its numbers fluctuated highly). Note that when testing with access logs on, that file system buffers cause unpredictable write delays when the log directory is on the SD card.