# Using a Pi to run a graph database (Neo4j)

Tags: web-server

I am doing some research into using the Pi to host an iOS app. It seems like the Pi's performance as a normal web server is actually quite impressive (especially when compared to the control server used in the [test](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/194/what-kind-of-performance-can-i-expect-from-using-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-webserver)).

[Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) is an open source NoSQL graph database. I think this could be a great solution for small apps needing this kind of backend.

Has anyone installed and tested the Pi running Neo4j? Is the performance acceptable?

Comment: Neo4j requires Java so that could be an issue, however, I run Jetty on my Pi which is also Java based.  Also, Oracle has a beta version of Java 8 available specifically for the Pi so that is good news also.

Comment: Note that the control server had a pretty pretty terrible spec as well.

Comment: I just installed Neo4j on my Raspberry and got big performance issues. It's so bad that i even can't perform big querrys.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?
https://gist.github.com/widged/8329039

*edit* added below instructions

Installation instructions for on a Pi :
**Install Java 7**

```
~:$ sudo apt-get update
~:$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk
~:$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
~:$ sudo apt-get install lsof
```

**Download Neo4J**

```
~:$ cd ~
~:$ mkdir neo4j
~:$ cd neo4j
~:$ wget -O neo4j-community-2.0.0.tgz 'http://download.neo4j.org/artifact?edition=community&version=2.0.0&distribution=tarball'
~:$ tar xvf neo4j-community-2.0.0.tgz
~:$ cd neo4j-community-2.0.0/conf
```

***OR for the newest branch***

```
~:$ wget -O neo4j-community-2.1.5.tgz 'http://download.neo4j.org/artifact?edition=community&version=2.1.5&distribution=tarball'
~:$ tar xvf neo4j-community-2.1.5.tgz
~:$ cd neo4j-community-2.1.5/conf
```

**Edit & Add Neo4J Propertie file**

```
~:$ nano neo4j.properties
 neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=1M
 neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=1M
 neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=1M
 neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1M
 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=1M
```

**Edit & Add Neo4J wrapper configuration**

```
~:$ nano neo4j-wrapper.conf
 wrapper.java.additional=-XX:MaxPermSize=32M
 wrapper.java.initmemory=96
 wrapper.java.maxmemory=96
```

**Make Neo4J known**

```
~:$ export NEO4J_HOME=~/neo4j/neo4j-community-2.0.0
OR
~:$ export NEO4J_HOME=~/neo4j/neo4j-community-2.1.5

~:$ export PATH=$NEO4J_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

**Run Neo4J **

```
~:$ neo4j status
~:$ neo4j start
```

For neo4j 2.0.0 this should work, 
I myself did not success with neo4j 2.1.5 but did not have time to look into it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ah.. Did not know that was a good thing to do.. Will Edit.