# Which graph database can ran on a Pi for small website?

Tags: server, database

I'm running a small website on a Pi B with tomcat / apache / mysql

I wish to migrate database to a graph db, Neo4J seems good on "real" server but not on Pi 
[as poorly mentionned here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4552/using-a-pi-to-run-a-graph-database-neo4j)

[OhmDB](http://www.ohmdb.com/) seems to be the closest choice, but ran in RAM

I found [mapgraph](http://mapgraph.io/), who ran on GPU but, what about running on a Pi

So, which engine should I try to run ?

Any advice to choose an open source lightweight database would be appreciated.

(edit)
The purpose of my question, is more in a "performance" view. I wish to know about which graph db implementation the pi is strong enough to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your research has already shown, you are unlikely to find any graph databases that perform well, can be installed on or run on the Pi. Remember the Pi (not Pi2) has similar performance characteristics to a Pentium powered computer. Most graph DB's are designed for large data sets and designed to run on large hardware (in production at least) compared to the Pi. Second there is very little demand for this type of software on the Pi, so most graph DB's are unlikely to have a version which will run on the Pi's arm processor.

Perhaps a better solution would be to use a cloud provider like AWS to stand up a dedicated instance for the graph database that you can connect to from your application (e.g. http://www.graphenedb.com/ for Neo4j). This would provide a greater number of DB's to chose from and vastly improve performance - even accounting for the network overhead.

Comment: You might look through [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database#Graph_database_projects), which at a glance includes [Bitsy](https://bitbucket.org/lambdazen/bitsy/wiki/Home).  I'd make sure you are using a hard float compiled java if you do that.

Comment: @goldilocks since it is in memory I doubt it will be performant with 512mb to share with the rest of the system. I can't say for sure but would expect a lot of swapping.